# Default value not set while using Update with Upsert as true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-update

I have the following model for users:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,
    dob: Date,
    sex: String,
    photo: String,
    email: {type: String, index: {unique: true, required: true}},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var User = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

As you can see the 'created' field takes a default value of the current date so that it is automatically set when a new user is created.

I use the following query when user details are posted:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({email: user.email}, user, {upsert: true}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return callback (err);
            } else {
                callback(null, user);
            }
        });
```

The purpose of using `findOneAndUpdate` with `upsert: true` is to either return an existing profile, or create a new one. It also updates any fields based on the data posted.

However, the `created` field gets updated with the current date each time, even though the created field is not posted. How can I make sure that this field is set only once?

**EDIT**

An example object from the database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54620b38b431d48bce7cab81"),
    "email" : "someone@google.com",
    "__v" : 0,
    "name" : "somone",
    "sex" : "male"
}
```

It turns out that the `created` field is not being set even while creating a new object using upsert. Mongoose just returns the current date based on the schema even though it does not exist in the document.

So, the question now becomes: How do I make sure that using `upsert` creates the default value for a field not supplied in the arguments?

Comment: Can you please write your `user` object in the question. So that I can try to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`findOneAndUpdate` simply sends a MongoDB `findAndModify` request (see [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)). What this means is that it skips all the mongoose magic involved with the schema setters, getters, defaults, etc. Validation is only run on create/save so the way around this is to do a `.findOne()`, check existence/create a new one, and then `.save()`.

[see this issue for more discussion](http://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/964)

**EDIT:**

In regards to the first question about changing the date each time, you could change the schema a bit. Get rid of the default value, and instead add this after declaring the schema:

```
UserSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    if (!this.created) {
        this.created = new Date();
    }
    next();
});
```

That will only create a date if the `created:` value is not present, and should prevent it from changing the creation date each time (when using `.save()`).

see Mongoose middleware

Comment: Thanks a lot @cdbajorin, I have gone with the approach of checking findOne and then saving a new entry if it returns null.

Answer (score 19):

For adding defaults to your document if it was created with `findOneAndUpdate` (it didn't exist before the query) and you did not provide the field in the update you should use [setDefaultsOnInsert](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate).

When `upsert` and `setDefaultsOnInsert` are both `true`, the defaults will be set if the record is not found and a new one is created.
This skips the workflow of having to check if the record exists and if not then creating a new one with 'save' just to make sure defaults are set.

I have had the same issue (record created with `findOneAndUpdate` with `upsert: true`) and the default value for a field was not added to the record, even though it was in the schema.
This is only in regards to adding defaults when using `findOneAndUpdate` to create documents, not for skipping the update of the 'created' field.

e.g.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({email: user.email}, user, {upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert:true}, ...)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. I've stopped it from being NAA. You should now consider improving it. See [answer].