# Auto Increment Sequence Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I implemented a auto increment sequence field in mongoose. I set the default/starting value as 5000. But it does not start from 5000, it starts from 1.

Heres my code:

**My Counter Schema**

```
// app/models/caseStudyCounter.js
// load the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// define the schema for our user model
var caseStudyCounterSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   _id: {type: String, required: true},
   seq: {type: Number, default: 5000}

});

// methods ======================

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('caseStudyCounter', caseStudyCounterSchema);
```

**My Main Schema:**

```
// grab the mongoose module
var caseStudyCounter = require('../models/caseStudyCounter');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

// grab the bcrypt module to hash the user passwords
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// define the schema for our model
var caseStudySchema = mongoose.Schema({
     caseStudyNo: Number,
     firstName: String,
     lastName: String,

 });

caseStudySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var doc = this;

caseStudyCounter.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: 'caId'},{$inc: { seq: 1}},{"upsert": true,"new": true  }, function(error, counter)   {
    if(error)
        return next(error);
    doc.caseStudyNo = counter.seq;
    next();
});

});
 // module.exports allows us to pass this to other files when it is called
 // create the model for users and expose it to our app
 module.exports = mongoose.model('CaseStudy', caseStudySchema);
```

**I can't figure out why its starting form 1 when I have set the default as 5000. The sequence should be 5001, 5002, 5003 and so on. Any help will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: you can install this module [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment)

Comment: you can create before to get find one last largest count and incremented save.

Comment: Probably is because of the upsert, can you please try creating the document if not exists and than update it?

Comment: Possible related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865357/default-value-not-set-while-using-update-with-upsert-as-true

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is why it happens: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3617#issuecomment-160296684

> Use the `setDefaultsOnInsert` option. Or just manually use `{$inc: {n:1}, $setOnInsert: {n:776} }`

Comment: Someone Said me mongodb is Document-oriented database and is not good for auto increments, Then Can I make a project without auto increments number?

Comment: It completely depends on the project

Comment: When we need auto increments numbers?

Comment: Yep, so use the above. If your app is heavy switch to another DB like Redis

Answer (score 0):

You can install [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment).

```
yourSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {
    model: 'model',
    field: 'field',
    startAt: 5000,
    incrementBy: 1
});
```

It's easy to install and use.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue so i came up with this solution.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

// define the schema for our model
var caseStudySchema = mongoose.Schema({
 caseStudyNo: {
  type:Number,
  default:5000
 },
 firstName: String,
 lastName: String,
});

caseStudySchema.pre('save', function(next) {

var doc = this;

//Retrieve last value of caseStudyNo
CaseStudy.findOne({},{},{sort: { 'caseStudyNo' :-1}}, function(error, counter)   {
//if documents are present in collection then it will increment caseStudyNo 
// else it will create a new documents with default values 
 
    if(counter){
      counter.caseStudyNo++;
      doc.caseStudyNo=counter.caseStudyNo;
    }
    next();
 });
});
// module.exports allows us to pass this to other files when it is called
// create the model for users and expose it to our app
const CaseStudy = mongoose.model('CaseStudy', caseStudySchema);
module.exports = CaseStudy;
```