# Mongoose set default on field update if field is not present or null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, updates, mongoose-schema, auto-update

I have a mongoose schema like this suppose:-

```
var mSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true}
});
```

and have been using this schema for a year and now i want to add gender to it like this :-

```
var mSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true},
  gender: { type: String, default: 'Male' } 
});
```

whenever there will be an update request i want this gender to automatically set Male as default but i found that default don't set on update request. 
(Note: It's just an example not a real life scenario. i just want mongoose default work if field is not present or null)

Is there any way in which i can set default on the updation of document ?

Comment: a possible solution is whenever you add a new field with a default, run updateMany query to initialize the field with the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a function like `update()`, then this is not directly possible as stated by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26868684/2856218) answer. Still, you can simply switch to a function like `findOne()` and use `save()`, which should do the same.

When upserting documents, you can also check out the `setDefaultsOnInsert` option: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#the-setdefaultsoninsert-option

```html
const options = {
  // Create a document if one isn't found. Required
  // for `setDefaultsOnInsert`
  upsert: true,
  setDefaultsOnInsert: true
};

await XY.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
```